# Best Statistical Test for my situation?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, recommender-system

For an upcoming project we are trying to create a recommendation algorithm for customers and providers.  I will have some number of service providers, probably hundreds to thousands, and some number of patients, hopefully thousands to tens of thousands.  I will have various characteristics of each, and data on whether the patient and provider were a good match.

The goal is to match patients to providers, and find out which pairings of characteristics predict success.

The question is what statistical tests should I be looking at?  And how do I estimate how much data is likely to be sufficient to find, say, a 10% improvement in the matching success rate?

If it was just for myself in a business context, I'd be happy to calculate a MLE for how much patient outcome seems to be correlated with the provider, then run a Monte Carlo simulation to see which correlations seem strong enough to investigate.  Then do a follow-up experiment to verify.  However the people that I am working with would like to publish, and so I'd like a more established approach.

Comment: Using a statistical test for your problem is a bad idea, too much data. You probably want a model / classifier.

Comment: @user2974951 Can you suggest a good starting point for me to learn more about appropriate model / classifiers?  My background is pure math 20 years ago, and a lot of software development since.

Comment: This question would need more details. However, I would guess that this could be solved with clustering. Take a look at http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/ chapter 10.